# Azure Static Web Apps: How to set the version of Node.js?

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

I want to use Node.js v12.x to build and deploy but it uses 14.15.1:

```
Using Node version:
v14.15.1

Using Npm version:
6.14.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the desired node.js version via the Azure CLI:
`az webapp config set --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <app-name> --linux-fx-version "NODE|12.X"`

For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-linux#set-nodejs-version

Answer (score 16):

If you arrived here wanting to set the Node.js runtime version that is used for your API backend, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#platform

In summary, you will create a `staticwebapp.config.json` that sits where your `app_location` is pointed in your github workflow (typically the root of your project) or any subfolder of `app_location`

You can then set the runtime like this...

```json
{
  "platform": {
    "apiRuntime": "node:16"
  }
}
```

At the time of writing, your options are `node:12`, `node:14`, `node:16`. Reference the link above for the most up to date values.\

I'd like to answer the original question as well because I think the accepted answer is wrong. The azure CLI will say that `az webapp ...` can't find your project because it's a `staticwebapp` not a `webapp`.

The solution (and I'm not certain) should be to set the `nodeEngines` in `package.json`, like this:

```json
{
  "engines": { 
    "npm": ">=7.0.0",
    "node": ">=16.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

If I'm wrong about this, let me know in the comments and I'll update it.

Comment: adding platform / apiRuntime to staticwebapp.config.json (as you described) fixed it for me

Comment: Agreed, for SWA, this is the correct answer.

Comment: Only valid in Linux, not in Windows